# SqlAlchemy Select Relation Type

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple One-to-Many relation mapped with SqlAlchemy:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Type(Base):

    __tablename__ = "entity_types"

    type = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String(300))

class Entity(Base):

    __tablename__ = "entities"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = Column('type', String(100), ForeignKey(Types.type), 
                     nullable=False)
    type = relation(Type, backref='entities')
    value = Column(Text, nullable=False)
```

I want to query all types ever used in an entity. In pure SQL I would accomplish this by:

```
SELECT entity_types.*
FROM entities
    JOIN entity_types ON entities.type == entity_types.type
GROUP BY entity_types.type
```

How do I solve this using SqlAlchemy's ORM-Engine?

I've tried these queries, but they all don't return what I want:

```
session.query(Action.type).group_by(Action.type).all()

session.query(Type).select_from(Action).group_by(Type).all()
```

I've also tried using `options(joinedload('type'))`, but I found out, this is only used to force eager loading and to bypass lazy-loading.

**ADDITION:** I've just added the `backref` in the `relation` of `Entity`. I think the problem is solvable by querying `count(Type.entities) > 0`, but I cannot figure out how to exactly form a valid ORM query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just figured it out:

```
session.query(ActionType).filter(ActionType.actions.any()).all()
```

The `any()` does the trick.